# Receiving error "ORA:22905-can not access rows from a non-nested table item" while working with ref cursors in JSON in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, json, plsql, table, cursors

I have created below procedure. I am getting ORA:22905-can not access rows from a non-nested table item at last line : INTO JSON_DATA FROM TABLE(InvoiceDetails). What I am doing here is retrieving out put from multiple queries dynamically through ref cursors and then passing the output to JSON.

```
PROCEDURE Calculate_Fields_Proc (p_invoice_number   IN     NUMBER,
                                     p_region           IN     VARCHAR2, --AMER/APJS/EMEA
                                     p_record_type      IN     VARCHAR2, --Invoice/Credit memo
                                     p_invoice_format   IN     VARCHAR2,
                                     p_o_json_data         OUT CLOB)
    IS
        --TYPE InvoiceDetails IS REF CURSOR;
        InvoiceDetails  SYS_REFCURSOR;
        --InvoiceDetails  InvoiceDetails;
        l_asset_tax_category_count   NUMBER;
        l_category_name              VARCHAR2 (50);
        l_cat_charge_total           NUMBER;
        l_cat_tax_total              NUMBER;
        l_cat_invoice_total          NUMBER;
        l_misc_charge_total          NUMBER;
        l_misc_tax_total             NUMBER;
        l_misc_invoice_total         NUMBER;
        l_inv_charge_total           NUMBER;
        l_inv_tax_total              NUMBER;
        l_inv_total                  NUMBER;
        l_cat_principal_total        NUMBER;
        l_cat_interest_total         NUMBER;
        JSON_ARR            JSON_ARRAY_T := JSON_ARRAY_T ();
        JSON_DATA                    CLOB;
    BEGIN
        OPEN InvoiceDetails FOR
               'SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT asset_tax_category) FROM ile_ar_charg_stage_trx chrg
                WHERE chrg.invoice_seq_id > '
                || p_invoice_number;

    LOOP
        FETCH InvoiceDetails INTO l_asset_tax_category_count;

        EXIT WHEN InvoiceDetails%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            'l_asset_tax_category_count: ' || l_asset_tax_category_count);
    END LOOP;

    OPEN InvoiceDetails FOR
           'SELECT asset_tax_category                     rec_category_name,
     SUM (charge_amount)                    Rec_cat_charge_total,
     SUM (
           NVL (tax_only_column, 0)
         + NVL (pst_tax_only_column, 0)
         + NVL (qst_tax_only_column, 0)
         + NVL (gst_tax_only_column, 0)
         + NVL (hst_tax_only_column, 0))    Rec_cat_tax_total,
     SUM (charge_total)                     Rec_cat_invoice_total
    FROM ile_ar_charg_stage_trx chrg
   WHERE chrg.invoice_seq_id = '
            || p_invoice_number
            || 'AND chrg.charge_type = ''0001''
   GROUP BY asset_tax_category';


    LOOP
        FETCH InvoiceDetails
            INTO l_category_name,
                 l_cat_charge_total,
                 l_cat_tax_total,
                 l_cat_invoice_total;

        EXIT WHEN InvoiceDetails%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
               l_category_name
            || ''
            || l_cat_charge_total
            || ''
            || l_cat_tax_total
            || ''
            || l_cat_invoice_total);
    END LOOP;

    OPEN InvoiceDetails FOR
           'SELECT SUM (charge_amount)                    misc_charge_total,
     SUM (
           NVL (tax_only_column, 0)
         + NVL (pst_tax_only_column, 0)
         + NVL (qst_tax_only_column, 0)
         + NVL (gst_tax_only_column, 0)
         + NVL (hst_tax_only_column, 0))    misc_tax_total,
     SUM (charge_total)                     misc_invoice_total
    FROM ile_ar_charg_stage_trx chrg
   WHERE chrg.invoice_seq_id = '
            || p_invoice_number
            || 'AND chrg.charge_type <> ''0001''
   GROUP BY asset_tax_category';


    LOOP
        FETCH InvoiceDetails
            INTO l_misc_charge_total,
                 l_misc_tax_total,
                 l_misc_invoice_total;

        EXIT WHEN InvoiceDetails%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
               l_misc_charge_total
            || ''
            || l_misc_tax_total
            || ''
            || l_misc_invoice_total);
    END LOOP;


    OPEN InvoiceDetails FOR
        'SELECT SUM (charge_amount)                    INV_CHARGE_TOTAL,
   SUM (
         NVL (tax_only_column, 0)
       + NVL (pst_tax_only_column, 0)
       + NVL (qst_tax_only_column, 0)
       + NVL (gst_tax_only_column, 0)
       + NVL (hst_tax_only_column, 0))    INV_TAX_TOTAL,
   SUM (charge_total)                     INV_TOTAL
  FROM ile_ar_charg_stage_trx chrg
 WHERE chrg.invoice_seq_id =' || p_invoice_number;


    LOOP
        FETCH InvoiceDetails
            INTO l_inv_charge_total, l_inv_tax_total, l_inv_total;

        EXIT WHEN InvoiceDetails%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
               l_inv_charge_total
            || ''
            || l_inv_tax_total
            || ''
            || l_inv_total);
    END LOOP;

    OPEN InvoiceDetails FOR
           'SELECT SUM (NVL (chrg.UD_CHARGE_PRINCIPAL_AMT, 0))
                   Rec_cat_principal_total,
               SUM (NVL (chrg.UD_CHARGE_INTEREST_AMT, 0))
                   Rec_cat_interest_total
          FROM ile_ar_charg_stage_trx chrg
         WHERE chrg.invoice_seq_id ='
                    || p_invoice_number
                    || 'AND charge_type = ''0001''';


    LOOP
        FETCH InvoiceDetails INTO l_cat_principal_total, l_cat_interest_total;


        EXIT WHEN InvoiceDetails%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
            l_cat_principal_total || '' || l_cat_interest_total);
    END LOOP;
    
       BEGIN
          SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(*))
          INTO JSON_DATA FROM TABLE(InvoiceDetails);  -- **getting error here**
           
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (JSON_DATA);
       END;

    CLOSE InvoiceDetails;
END;
```

Comment: A REF CURSOR isn't a collection object, so you can't use the TABLE operator on it or treat it like a row source. It's simple a cursor (SQL statement), that is, a program. It can only be executed by opening and fetching from it as you are rightly doing elsewhere in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using ref cursors and dynamic SQL?

Looking through your SQL statements, there is no need for dynamic SQL at all - not to mention you're converting from bind variables to concatenating a literal value, and leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection to boot! Also, you can use conditional aggregation to combine some of the queries, meaning you only need 3 queries after all.

Finally, you can avoid all the looping and output the JSON by taking each query, converting the output into JSON and joining them together.

Thus (and I had to guess at how you wanted your output), your function could be rewritten more efficiently and easier to debug like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calculate_fields_proc(p_invoice_number IN NUMBER,
                                                  p_region         IN VARCHAR2, --AMER/APJS/EMEA
                                                  p_record_type    IN VARCHAR2, --Invoice/Credit memo
                                                  p_invoice_format IN VARCHAR2,
                                                  p_o_json_data    OUT CLOB) IS
BEGIN

  SELECT json_serialize(json_object(key 'asset_tax_category_cnt' VALUE qry1.asset_tax_category_cnt,
                                    key 'output_per_category' VALUE qry2.output_per_category,
                                    key 'totals' VALUE qry3.totals) RETURNING CLOB pretty) RESULT
  INTO   p_o_json_data
  FROM   (SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object(*)) asset_tax_category_cnt
          FROM   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT asset_tax_category) asset_tax_category_cnt
                  FROM   ile_ar_charg_stage_trx chrg
                  WHERE  chrg.invoice_seq_id > p_invoice_number)) qry1
  CROSS  JOIN (SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object(*)) output_per_category
               FROM   (SELECT asset_tax_category rec_category_name,
                              SUM(CASE
                                    WHEN chrg.charg_type = '0001' THEN
                                     charge_amount
                                  END) rec_cat_charge_total,
                              SUM(CASE
                                    WHEN chrg.charg_type = '0001' THEN
                                     NVL(tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(pst_tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(qst_tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(gst_tax_only_column, 0) +
                                     NVL(hst_tax_only_column, 0)
                                  END) rec_cat_tax_total,
                              SUM(CASE
                                    WHEN chrg.charg_type = '0001' THEN
                                     charge_total
                                  END) rec_cat_invoice_total,
                              SUM(CASE
                                    WHEN chrg.charg_type != '0001' THEN
                                     charge_amount
                                  END) misc_charge_total,
                              SUM(CASE
                                    WHEN chrg.charg_type != '0001' THEN
                                     NVL(tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(pst_tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(qst_tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(gst_tax_only_column, 0) +
                                     NVL(hst_tax_only_column, 0)
                                  END) misc_tax_total,
                              SUM(CASE
                                    WHEN chrg.charg_type != '0001' THEN
                                     charge_total
                                  END) misc_invoice_total
                       FROM   ile_ar_charg_stage_trx chrg
                       WHERE  chrg.invoice_seq_id = p_invoice_number
                       GROUP  BY asset_tax_category)) qry2
  CROSS  JOIN (SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object(*)) totals
               FROM   (SELECT SUM(charge_amount) inv_charge_total,
                              SUM(NVL(tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(pst_tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(qst_tax_only_column, 0) + NVL(gst_tax_only_column, 0) +
                                  NVL(hst_tax_only_column, 0)) inv_tax_total,
                              SUM(charge_total) inv_total,
                              SUM(CASE
                                    WHEN chrg.charg_type = '0001' THEN
                                     chrg.ud_charge_principal_amt
                                  END) rec_cat_principal_total,
                              SUM(CASE
                                    WHEN chrg.charg_type = '0001' THEN
                                     chrg.ud_charge_interest_amt
                                  END) rec_cat_interest_total
                       FROM   ile_ar_charg_stage_trx chrg
                       WHERE  chrg.invoice_seq_id = p_invoice_number)) qry3;
END calculate_fields_proc;
/
```

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cgPoO6qO) for an example of it working.